# Is there a more elegant way to transform a string into an array?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I would like to convert a string of 11 digits into an array. Is there a more elegant way to do this in ColdFusion 9?

```
local.string = [];

for (local.i = 1; local.i <= len(arguments.string); local.i++)
{
    local.string[ local.i ] = mid(arguments.string, local.i, 1);
}
```

If my string were `12345`, then the array would look like `string[1] = 1; string[2] = 2`, etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an elegant way which I think will work in any version of ColdFusion.

The trick is to use CF's list manipulation functions - if you specify a delimiter of "" (i.e. nothing) it will see each character of the string as a list item.

So what you want is:

```
local.string = listToArray(arguments.string, "");
```

And that will give you your array of characters...

Comment: Thanks, I tried listToArray() first but, unfortunately, my brain wasn't on par to figure out the delimiter argument correctly!

Comment: FYI: It might be CF9 only. The result is a single element array in CF8.

Comment: @Leigh, at least one other person thinks you're correct: this behavior has been [reported as a bug](http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=84125) in CF9, and part of that report repeats what you said, that in CF8, it would simply return the original string.

Comment: @Dave - Yes, I kind of agree with the other Dave. It is neat, but does have the feel of an "unintentional feature" ;)

Answer (score 6):

This works on CF8 and doesn't rely on the "bug" in CF9:

```
stringAsList = REReplace( string,"(.)","\1,","ALL" );
array = ListToArray( stringAsList );
```

Comment: @CFSimplicty, interesting.. so, if I understand this correctly, the behaviour of listToArray(string, "") is a bug? I'm not really interesting in ColdFusion 8, but I don't want this function to break in future versions...

Comment: @Mohamad, guess it's a matter of opinion whether it's a bug or feature (personally I'd say a bug: a list delimiter must surely be least 1 character long), but it's probably best not to rely on it in case Adobe decide it needs fixing.

Comment: Nice one. I think it could even be a one liner with reMatch: `result = Rematch("(.)", string);`

Comment: @Leigh: you don't need the parentheses, but otherwise this is the best  "native CFML" answer I've seen for this.

Comment: @AdamCameron - Yeah, you are right. I guess since there are no backreferences, all you need is `rematch(".", string)`. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the java method String.split(), it returns a String[], so you'll have to copy it's values into a new array eg. `myArray = arrayNew(1)` + `myArray.addAll( myStringArr )`.

Answer (score -2):

Interesting, it appears that you can do something similar using the .split() java method and get similar results.

A bit of background: since CF is built on Java, it can take advantage of many of the underlying java methods and classes. According to Rupesh Kuman of Adobe (http://coldfused.blogspot.com/2007/01/extend-cf-native-objects-harnessing.html), a CF array is an implementation of java.util.List, so all the list methods are also available for CF arrays. One of the more useful ones is the .split() method. This takes a string and turns it into an array based on an arbitrary delimiter of 0 or more characters.

Here's what I did: set a list to be an 11 digit number, used the split method to create the array and then displayed the result.

```
    <cfset testList = "12345678901" />
    <cfset testArray = testList.split("") />
    <cfset request.cfdumpinited = false />
    <cfdump label="testArray" expand="true" var="#testArray#"/>
    <cfabort />
```

If you run this, you see that you end up with a 12 item array with the first index item being empty. Just delete that one using ArrayDelete() or ArrayDeleteAt() and you should be good to go. This should work with all versions of ColdFusion since CFMX 6.

Comment: split() is a method of java.lang.String not List. Also `ArrayDeleteAt(testArray)` will fail because the returned array is immutable. It is not a java.util.List object.

Comment: Pick nits much? the point being the questioner was looking for an alternative method of creating an array from a cf based list. I think that my answer did such.

Comment: BTW just ran isArray(testArray)  it returned a yes. So not sure who or what is correct.

Comment: Fact is your suggestion does not produce desired results, an array without extra elements. The others do. Try not to take things so personally.

Comment: Yes, isArray() will misleadingly return true. `testArray` is a java String[] array. But it is not a CF array (ie java.util.List). That is why ArrayDeleteAt fails. One of the many nuances of java objects. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29